# Calling Oracle stored procedure from Node js

Tags: node.js, oracle

```
const oracledb = require("oracledb");
const config = require('../configuration/config')

const fefficiency = async (req, res) => {
    let connection;


    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(config.bsp_connection);
    const result = await connection.execute(
        `BEGIN
        SELECT BPS_GRAPH_PKG.F_EFFICIENCY(:param1, :param2) FROM DUAL;
        END;`,
        {
            param1: '463',
            param2: 'MAY-2023'
        }
    );
    console.log('Procedure executed successfully');
};

module.exports = { fefficiency }
```

I get an error when trying to run this code:

> C:\nodejs\eagleapi\controllers\bpsgraphs.js:11
>
> connection = await oracledb.getConnection(config.bsp_connection);
> ^
>
> Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>
> ORA-20202: You Are Not Allowed To Connect With Database Using Unauthorized Program
> ORA-06512: at line 200
>
> at async fefficiency (C:\nodejs\eagleapi\controllers\bpsgraphs.js:11:16) {
> errorNum: 604,
> offset: 0
> }

Comment: Errors 20000 to 20999 are user-defined error codes. You need to look through the source code on the database to find where someone else has written the code that is generating this error and then look at what you need to do to work with the existing code (or, if appropriate, disable the existing code) so that you can connect to the database. StackOverflow cannot help you with this because it is a problem local to your database and no-one other than you and your colleagues has access to the source code to identify the problem.

Comment: You may well find that you are looking for a logon trigger that raises the exception.